# Flutter Blue write characteristic issue

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter blue to connect to hc06 bluetooth module. An error occurs when trying to send data to a module.

My function:

```
writeData(String data) async {
if (targetCharacteristic == null) return;
print("${targetCharacteristic.toString()}+++++++");
targerDevice.canSendWriteWithoutResponse;
List<int> bytes = utf8.encode(data);
await targetCharacteristic?.write(bytes, withoutResponse: true);}
```

[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKYj7.png)

[debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KcJp.png)

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic doesn't support writing. See debug console.

```
... writeWithoutResponse: false, write: false ...
```